# Deploy laravel on azure server

Tags: php, laravel, azure, laravel-5, azure-web-app-service

My project is developed with larval, then i am trying to use azure for web server.

I am copying folder laravel in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\laravel5.
 Next I run php artisan serve.

Then I test on http://localhost:8000/index (test on remote websever). It's ok.

But if I access my url for example http://bobdict.cloudapp.net/index, it say page not found.

Comment: More information is needed. What exact OS version are you running? What web server are you using? Can you paste relevant web server configuration (such as sites-enabled under nginx)?

Comment: Also, if you aren't aware, Azure does have Ubuntu and other Linux images.

Comment: I use vm in azure and ise iis

Comment: And i use xampp in window server to accress by url

Comment: Okay. If the route is working fine on your development machine but not on your Azure server, then it's evident that either the web server or the Laravel installation is misconfigured. Does serving plain HTML files outside of a Laravel installation work?

Comment: How can i accress laravel index ?

Comment: After i use php artisan serve

Comment: Have you ran `composer install` and followed the Laravel installation guide to the letter? Have you pointed your web server to `public/index.php` under your Laravel installation?

Comment: Also, have you configured IIS properly for Laravel using online guides? It's not as simple as running `php artisan serve` with IIS.

Comment: How to change root doc to public

Comment: Yes i think so but how to config iis?

Comment: Follow this link: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/iis7-laravel-5

Comment: By the way, using Laravel under a Linux environment (preferably LEMP stack) is a much nicer and easier install.

Comment: Ok i am trying thx u

Comment: hey i can accress laravel now like http://nontestapp.cloudapp.net/
but route isnot working if i use http://nontestapp.cloudapp.net/index

Comment: 404 - File or directory not found.

Comment: Can you paste your routes.php file?

Comment: yes iam sure route is ok because i test on localhost it ok

Comment: <?php



Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::controller('index', 'IndexController');

Route::controllers([
 'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
 'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);

Comment: Is /home working? Do you have web.config under the public folder configured to handle the correct paths?

Comment: Make sure you've followed the Laracasts instructions I sent you above to the letter.

Comment: Please consider continuing your discussion in a [private chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/new). It's getting a bit out of hand to be in the comments section.